# In my app there is no resources folder. How can I add the resources folder in my app to add images and custom fonts

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode10.3

In my Xcode there is no resources under target. How can I add resources under target file

Comment: The folder `Resources` is created during the build process and exists only inside the application bundle.

Comment: @vadian I have created a new app in react-native.Here I need to add images and custom fonts. Build process is succeeded. Where the resources is found in my case. In my existing project I not created the resources file.

Comment: It's not in the project, it's in the built application. The images and fonts are copied to the folder automatically.

Comment: I need to add new fonts and images. In this case I need to add this. How I can add that without finding the resources folder. Or can you explain how you add custom images and fonts.

Comment: For iOS need to add static images and fonts for me

Comment: You cannot add items to the bundle at runtime. One again at compile time all resources are automatically copied to the implicit created `Resources` folder inside the application bundle.

Comment: In my previous app I have add like this. https://medium.com/@kswanie21/custom-fonts-in-react-native-tutorial-for-ios-android-76ceeaa0eb78

Comment: Are you mention, So initially i not need to add create like this for iOS and Android